# How do I set a mybatis property in spring boot application.properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am working on a spring boot application which uses mybatis. My mybatis mapper xml has a SQL query which contains a database schema name that needs to be set from the application properties. I have a schema name and I want to reference it in my `mapper.xml` as ${schema-name}. I can do this in `mybatis-config.xml` - something like this:

```
<configuration>    
   <PropertiesSource url='my properties file"/>   
   <properties>
     <property name='schema-name' value='${database.schema}'/> 
   </properties>
</configuration>
```

But I don't want to use `mybatis-config.xml`. I want to use the spring boot `application.properties` for mybatis configuration.

Is there a way to set the mybatis configuration property in spring boot application.properties? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I couldn't find an exact answer, but here are the available properties for mybatis: http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/ it's located on the bottom of the page

Comment: why you don't want use mybaits-config.xml, can used in application.properties like mybatis.config-location=classpath:/mybatis-config.xml

Answer (score 5):

- If you use the mybatis-spring-boot-starter 1.2.0, you can specify as follows:

  ```
  mybatis.configuration-properties.schema-name=abc
  ```

  or

  ```
  mybatis.configuration.variables.schema-name=abc
  ```
- If you use the mybatis-spring-boot-starter 1.1.1, you can specify as follow:

  ```
  mybatis.configuration.variables.schema-name=abc
  ```
- If you use the mybatis-spring-boot-starter 1.0.x, you cannot specify on application.properties. (please update to 1.1.1+)

Please try it.

Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

In the application.properties file put:

```
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host/table_name
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```